# Build configuration error using Android NDK

Tags: intellij-idea, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

There is a build configuration error (Gradle sync failed) starting a new simple Android project using `IntelliJ IDEA` and the installed `Android SDK` (API 28) to include C++ support.

If I can remember, it worked when first installed, but now any attempt to compile and build the project using the `IntelliJ GUI` fail. `LLDB, CMake and NDK` are all installed correctly in the correct folders and the `local.properties file` references the location of the `SDK and NDK`.

All attempts to refresh linked C++ projects or clear caches (invalidate caches/restart) make no difference.

CMake_server_log.txt suggests:

> CMAKE SERVER: CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program
>   corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You
>   probably need to select a different build tool.

Build output (edited to remove path):

> Cause: executing external native build for cmake CMakeLists.txt

There appears to be a lack of configuration to complete the build or missing `PATH` or `ENVIRONMENT` variable. Should I manually try to change this or add some extra code to the `build.gradle` or `CMakeLists.tx`t? There is the ninja application in the `cmake bin directory`.

Even importing other `NDK` sample projects fail (after downloading any required dependencies e.g. Gradle version).

Reinstalling `LLDB, CMake` and the `NDK` via SDK Tools do not solve the issue either.

I get the impression that I need to completely uninstall `IntelliJ IDEA` on Windows and remove any remaining folders/files associated with it, before reinstalling it. That would be a shame as `IntelliJ IDEA` works for other type of Android projects not requiring native C++ support.

Comment: If you have another CMake installed and for whatever reason it gets invoked for this build, that could explain your symptoms. No, I can't tell how this can be painlessly fixed, but you won't loose much if you use `make` as CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There appears to be no other CMake program files installed. How could CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM be configured in a project file or system-wide? Perhaps the solution is to install Android Studio 3.3 on the same computer, presumably accessing the same Android SDK (as I know the SDK is independent of IntelliJ IDEA, unless mistaken), although I was hoping just to stick to one Android IDE.  Or may try the command line only without an IDE.

Comment: Yes, gradle command line may be easier to debug than whatever IntelliJ decides to run for you (`gradlew assembleDebug`). With android.application plugin, we use `        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                    arguments "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make", "-GUnix Makefiles"
                }
            }
        }` in **build.gradle** to use *make* instead of *ninja*.

Comment: In fact, exciting IntelliJ IDEA and running gradlew from the command line works to build the APK successfully. However adding the CMake arguments to build.gradle in IntelliJ IDEA lead to the same build output error(s): External Native Build Issues: Error configuring.CMake_server_Log.txt, 'CMAKE SERVER: CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: Running 'make' '--version' failed with: The system cannot find the file specified'. Presumably it needs to be added to CMakeLists.txt or may be the environmental PATH. The CMakeLists.txt file was always left unaltered. NDK required for OpenCL/CPU-GPU acceleration.